# [HOMEWORK]Parallel image processing

Tags: c++, c, image-processing

To clear the air and avoid answers like post your code and etc, this is a theoretical question.I only seek advice or ways to accomplish my goal, i will give you my approach and i only need some guidance.
 As i said in the title this is a homework, basically i need to take some problem/algorithm and do a parallel implementation of it in 4 different ways like MPI,java threads,pragmaOMP etc. I was thinking of applying a sin city effect on a picture.Here is my sequential approach:

Lets say i want to keep the red color from a photo and convert the rest to grayscale. I convert the entire picture from RGB to HSV. In the HSV mode i change the saturation to everything but the reds to grey. Then convert back to RGB.

I want to know how can i go for a parallel implementation of this.Lets say i have n workers, i simply split the image into n parts and each worker works on that part of the image ? Or is there a better way of going parallel on such a program. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Image processing is generally very friendly to threading and using N workers for N parts of the image is a good idea. If you are allowed try using OpenCL. It's really nice for these kinds of things.

Comment: In your case, each of R, G, B can be a one-dimensional array of size `width * height`. When doing your processing, divide this array into `N` chunks and process each chunk individually. Handling the channels as 1D arrays may be simpler than working in 2D.

Comment: @Hugo , yes i am aware of OpenCL / OpenCV but i think it will be too easy for an assignment this way as it does pretty much everything i just need to parallel the behaviour. misha , that seems like a good idea, especially since OpenMPI can't send 2d arrays (or i dont know how :D)

Comment: @user2947880: You're correct that OpenCV can pretty much just do this for you. The same is *not* true of OpenCL though. OpenCL is basically just a programming language for parallel processing, typically used for executing code on the GPU.

Comment: @JerryCoffin , i understand.I somehow thought it was an alternative to OpenCV, my bad. Then i will definitely look at it. Thanks